checkboxes & multi-selection for rows in table on mobile
We are adapting desktop pages with a large table, to be usable on mobile devices. The table has multiple columns, edit icons on the right, and a checkbox on the left side. Above that checkbox column is a select-all checkbox - a pretty standard pattern.
In mobile, we're finding ways to collapse the multiple columns, but I'm curious about the best patterns and expectations of that checkbox column and the 'select all'
I'm seeking input on best solutions, as the checkbox does take up space. There's an argument to be made for the user not doing bulk edits on a mobile device, but I'd like to explore all options.

In mobile version, long press acts as a checkbox. When a row is long pressed and selected, then we can keep the row highlighted and show an icon, like a tick mark, on the extreme right (as no other row icons are going to get used at this stage).
